# Faithfull flatness of a module containing the ring as a direct summand

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, modules, flatness

Let $R$ be a not necessarily commutative ring, and let $M$ be a projective left $R$-module.

> **Question.** If $R$ is a direct summand of $M$ as a left $R$-module, then is it
> true that $M$ is faithfully flat as a left $R$-module?

Comment: Sorry - a stupid typo. It's fixed now.

Comment: Yes. $M$ is flat, and for every nonzero right $R$-module $N$, $N\otimes _RM$ contains a copy of $N$, hence is nonzero. This is one of the characterizations of faithfully flat modules.

Comment: @abx: What is a reference for this?

Comment: No, it's ok, I guess it's obvious.